# bash trap interrupt command but should exit on end of loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I´ve asked [Bash trap - exit only at the end of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797953/bash-trap-exit-only-at-the-end-of-loop) and the submitted solution works but while pressing CTRL-C the running command in the script (mp3convert with lame) will be interrupt and than the complete for loop will running to the end. Let me show you the simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mp3convert () { lame -V0 file.wav file.mp3 }

PreTrap() { QUIT=1 }

CleanUp() {
  if [ ! -z $QUIT ]; then
     rm -f $TMPFILE1
     rm -f $TMPFILE2
     echo "... done!" && exit
  fi }

trap PreTrap SIGINT SIGTERM SIGTSTP
trap CleanUp EXIT

case $1 in
     write)
           while [ -n "$line" ]
             do
                mp3convert
                [SOMEMOREMAGIC]
                CleanUp
             done
    ;;
QUIT=1
```

If I press CTRL-C while function mp3convert is running the lame command will be interrupt and then [SOMEMOREMAGIC] will execute before CleanUp is running. I don´t understand why the lame command will be interrupt and how I could avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to simplify the discussion above, I wrap up an easier understandable version of show-case script below. This script also HANDLES the "double control-C problem":
(Double control-C problem: If you hit control C twice, or three times, depending on how many `wait $PID` you used, those clean up can not be done properly.)

```
#!/bin/bash

mp3convert () {
  echo "mp3convert..."; sleep 5; echo "mp3convert done..."
}

PreTrap() {
  echo "in trap"
  QUIT=1
  echo "exiting trap..."
}

CleanUp() {
  ### Since 'wait $PID' can be interrupted by ^C, we need to protected it
  ### by the 'kill' loop  ==> double/triple control-C problem.
  while kill -0 $PID >& /dev/null; do wait $PID; echo "check again"; done

  ### This won't work (A simple wait $PID is vulnerable to double control C)
  # wait $PID

  if [ ! -z $QUIT ]; then
     echo "clean up..."
     exit
 fi
}

trap PreTrap SIGINT SIGTERM SIGTSTP
#trap CleanUp EXIT

for loop in 1 2 3; do
    (
      echo "loop #$loop"
      mp3convert
      echo magic 1
      echo magic 2
      echo magic 3
    ) &
    PID=$!
    CleanUp
    echo "done loop #$loop"
done
```

The `kill -0` trick can be found in a comment of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

Comment: You may just run it and test it. (See what message it prints, Hit many control-C's in between, etc...)

Comment: Yes - thats the solution. The trick are that all commands that could not interrupt must be grouped (via round brackets) and execute as a background job.

Comment: Parenthesis (round brackets) actually forks a new sub-shell.

Comment: The double(triple or more) control-C problem should be generalized by "double signal/trap problem", since it is not limited to control-C (SIGINT), but also other signals.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit Ctrl-C in a terminal, SIGINT gets sent to all processes in the foreground process group of that terminal, as described in this Stack Exchange "Unix & Linux" answer: [How Ctrl C works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/88378). (The other answers in that thread are well worth reading, too). And that's why your mp3convert function gets interrupted even though you have set a SIGINT trap.

But you can get around that by running the mp3convert function in the background, as mattias mentioned. Here's a variation of your script that demonstrates the technique.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myfunc() 
{
    echo -n "Starting $1 :"
    for i in {1..7}
    do
        echo -n " $i"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo ". Finished $1"
}

PreTrap() { QUIT=1; echo -n " in trap "; }

CleanUp() {
    #Don't start cleanup until current run of myfunc is completed.
    wait $pid
    [[ -n $QUIT ]] &&
    {
        QUIT=''
        echo "Cleaning up"
        sleep 1
        echo "... done!" && exit
    } 
}

trap PreTrap SIGINT SIGTERM SIGTSTP
trap CleanUp EXIT

for i in {a..e}
do
    #Run myfunc in background but wait until it completes.
    myfunc "$i" &
    pid=$!
    wait $pid
    CleanUp
done

QUIT=1
```

When you hit  Ctrl-C while `myfunc` is in the middle of a run, `PreTrap` prints its message and sets the QUIT flag, but `myfunc` continues running and `CleanUp` doesn't commence until the current `myfunc` run has finished.

Note that my version of `CleanUp` resets the QUIT flag. This prevents `CleanUp` from running twice.

---

This version removes the `CleanUp` call from the main loop and puts it inside the `PreTrap` function. It uses `wait` with no ID argument in `PreTrap`, which means we don't need to bother saving the PID of each child process. This should be ok since if we're in the trap we *do* want to wait for all child processes to complete before proceeding.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Yet another Trap demo...

myfunc() 
{
    echo -n "Starting $1 :"
    for i in {1..5}
    do
        echo -n " $i"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo ". Finished $1"
}

PreTrap() { echo -n " in trap "; wait; CleanUp; }

CleanUp() {
    [[ -n $CLEAN ]] && { echo bye; exit; }

    echo "Cleaning up"
    sleep 1
    echo "... done!" 
    CLEAN=1

    exit
}

trap PreTrap SIGINT SIGTERM SIGTSTP
trap "echo exittrap; CleanUp" EXIT

for i in {a..c}
do
    #Run myfunc in background but wait until it completes.
    myfunc "$i" &  wait $!
done
```

We don't really need to do `myfunc "$i" &  wait $!` in this script, it could be simplified even further to `myfunc "$i" &  wait`. But generally it's better to wait for a specific PID just in case there's some other process running in the background that we *don't* want to wait for.

Note that pressing Ctrl-C while `CleanUp` itself is running will interrupt the current foreground process (probably `sleep` in this demo).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are there a solution for a script with many commands that do not shall interrupt? Do I have to use the 3 lines for every command? And why do you think it is necessary to unset the QUIT variable?

Comment: @UsersUser: Those 3 lines can be written as one line: `myfunc "$i" & pid=$!; wait $pid`. But I'll add a simpler version of my script to my answer. As for your last question, if I don't reset QUIT then cleanup runs twice; at least, it does on my system.

Comment: I´ve tried your solution but it doesn´t work like I expect. If I execute your script and press CTRL-C into one loop I get:
`./testloop.sh`
`Starting a : 1 2 3^C in trap Cleaning up`
`... done!`

It seams so that by pressing SIGINT it will go to PreTrap but also interrupt the running command.

Comment: An another point: If I delete your `QUIT=1` at the end it doesn´t execute CleanUp function, but it should execute CleanUp in line 39.

    ./testloop.sh
    Starting a : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. Finished a
    Starting b : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. Finished b
    Starting c : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. Finished c
    Starting d : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. Finished d
    Starting e : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. Finished e

My Bash version is `4.3.30(1)-release`

Comment: For your second example: I can´t find the declaration of `$CLEAN` which do you use in `CleanUp`.

Comment: @UsersUser: It's weird that these scripts don't work properly on your system. I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)`. In both of my scripts `myfunc` should finish even if the script receives CTRL-C. Do they work properly if you send SIGTERM?

Comment: If you delete `QUIT=1` at the end of the 1st script then `CleanUp` will be run by the EXIT trap, but it will do nothing because of the `[[ -n $QUIT ]]` test. The 2nd script doesn't bother to initialize `CLEAN` because `[[ -n $CLEAN ]]` will evaluate to false if `CLEAN` is an empty string _or_ uninitialized. Some people don't like this style, but it is a fairly common practice.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to simply disable the interrupt until your program is done.
Some pseudo code follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First, store your stty settings and disable the interrupt
STTY=$(stty -g) 
stty intr undef

#run your program here
runMp3Convert()

#restore stty settings
stty ${STTY}

# eof
```

Another idea would be to run your bash script in the background (if possible).

```
mp3convert.sh &
```

or even,

```
nohup mp3convert.sh &
```

Comment: No, I need the chance to interrupt the script but I need a complete loop run. Unfortunaly the lame command are the longest running part of the loop and if I disable the interrupt I´ve got a minimized chance to interrupt the script because of a very little time slot.

Comment: Ok, now I understand :) - I could use this to disable the interrupt for the whole function but not for the script. But I don´t know how robust this code are - I never used `stty` before and I don´t know how compatible it is with other *nix/*bsd os.

Comment: @UsersUser: Well play around with it and try to verify its usability. I just know that it works for the example I gave. And, please consider accepting the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Well, it helped me, but the answer from @pm-2ring explains a lot more and it helped me to understood your answer :). If I had more reputation points I would vote your answer up.

Comment: After think again: I don´t think that your solution will help me. I could not send a SIGINT to the script while running `runMp3Convert()` and the chance to interrupt the script in the other time are short.